# Finding the name and area of layer under buffers

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, area, identify

I am new to QGIS and am using version 3.34.2 (Prizren). I am using two files to accomplish a couple of tasks (explained below). The first file shows the outline of groups of villages (gram panchayat [GP]) in West Bengal, India (downloaded from [SHRUG](https://www.devdatalab.org/shrug)) and the other is the National Family Health Survey [NFHS] cluster-level geocodes (from the [DHS](https://dhsprogram.com/) website).

[image: Figure 1]

The image above (figure 1) shows both files in QGIS.

**SHRUG Village level file**: The green shapefile shows the GPs in West Bengal

**NFHS file**:

1. The orange dots are the (displaced) locations provided by the NFHS. By displaced, I mean that these are not the exact cluster locations, however, a 5 km buffer around the dots gives us the area within which the household cluster is located.
2. The purple circles are 5-kilometre buffers around the surveyed (rural) household clusters.

*For each buffer (cluster), I want to find out*

1. the names of GPs that are within the buffer.
2. the area of the GPs within each buffer.

[image: Figure 2]

For the two tasks (from figure 1 and 2), I want the area of the GP under each buffer [figure 1] and name (field name 'Combined_4') [figure 2] of each GP under the buffer. So far, I have tried 'clipping' by going to Vector->Geoprocessig Tools->Clip. That seems to do something but fails to accomplish the main tasks.

How can I accomplish the two tasks in QGIS?

Comment: Your Question does not contain a question, but it seems you're looking for the Intersect procedure.

Comment: Use Overlap Analysis from the processing toolbox.

Comment: In addition to the Overlap Analysis tool for other analyses, you can run an Overlay tool like Union or Intersect, recalculate or add a new area field and then run a pivot table (there is a pivot table tool in QGIS but I would typically copy and paste the new tabular data into a spreadsheet for analysis.